# fog Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm really stuck with this, I tried to find an answer on StackOverflow, but nothing really worked, I hope someone can give me some advices.
Everything was working fine locally, before adding the AWS parameters and still working when I dont upload a picture on a profile.

Main problem >>

ArgumentError in Devise::RegistrationsController#update

 Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id

Here is the user.rb : (maybe my storage is wrong or the credentials , or maybe I dont initiate the file with all the Aws_key_ID )

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_attached_file :avatar,
    :styles => {
      :medium => "300x300>",
      :thumb => "100x100#"
      },
    :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png",
    :url  => ":s3_domain_url",
    :path => "public/avatars/:id/:style_:basename.:extension",
    :storage => :fog,
    #Configuration for Amazon S3
    :fog_credentials => {
        provider: 'AWS',
        region: 'Frankfurt',
        aws_access_key_id: ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
        aws_secret_access_key: ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]
    },
        fog_directory: ENV["FOG_DIRECTORY"]

    validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

GemFile :

```
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.1'
gem 'devise'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'fog'
gem 'figaro'
```

application.yml

```
SECRET_KEY_BASE: 'XXXXXxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: 'xxxxxxxxxQ'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: 'yxxxxxxx'
EMAIL_LOGIN: 'xxx@gmail.com'
EMAIL_PASSWORD: 'xxxxxx'
development:
  FOG_DIRECTORY: demo-dev
production:
  FOG_DIRECTORY: demo-production
```

secret.yml

```
development:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>

test:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>

production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Should I add something in the production.rb file ?

Hope you will find some advices to help me :D

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you haven' configured correctly when loading `fog_credentials`, so it would be:

```
config = YAML::load_file('config/application.yml')
...
:fog_credentials => {
  provider: 'AWS',
  region: 'Frankfurt',
  aws_access_key_id: config["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
  aws_secret_access_key: config["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]
}
...
```

Because you haven't set any env variables for it, but you already defined it in you application.yml, so just load them up

Comment: It worked, i got another problem with S3 credentials but it worked for that part ;)

Comment: finally changed the region , and everything was working fine

Comment: Happy to hear that :) @MartinRails

Answer (score 0):

Despite this thread being quite old, I've had this same issue recently with a legacy project and figured out that ENVs that are set on `config/application.yml` won't be available on the CarrierWave initializer at the time it loads for some reason I can't explain.

I've then replaced variables like:

```
# config/initializers/carrierwave.rb

aws_access_key_id: config["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
aws_secret_access_key: config["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]
```

with

```
aws_access_key_id: Rails.application.secrets.aws_access_key_id
aws_secret_access_key: Rails.application.secrets.aws_secret_access_key
```

and added them to `config/secrets.yml` instead and that has worked great.

Hope that helps someone in the future!